# How to insert variable value into textbox using Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the code for my text box in ASP.NET MVC's Razor markup language:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, when the user first navigates to the page, the text box is empty.

However, I would like the text box to be filled with the value for `m.FullName` when the user first navigates to the page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Set the value of `FullName` in your GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: SET model on controller

Comment: `FullName` already has a value (ie. it is not an empty or null string). I just need to display it in the text box. Can either of you please send me the line of code that can do this? Perhaps an edited `@Html.TextBoxFor(...)`?

Comment: In your code snippet, TextBox control is already bound with "FullName" field, so if the FullName property is having any value, then it should be displayed to the text box. No additional code is required. Just debug through the view, and inspect what do you get in "@Model.FullName"?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })` is already correct. If FullName contains a value, it'll be displayed in the textbox. So the problem is most likely that you haven't set a value for it in the model object. We can't help you with that because you haven't given any indication about how your model is populated. You need to populate the model object in the action method which is used to create this view, and pass that object to the view. Any basic MVC tutorial will show you how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being exactly what the commenters suggested. Specifically:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        // Edit the Microsoft GraphServiceClient user first ...

        // Here is where I went wrong - I didn't pass in myEditedUser
        return View("Edit", myEditedUser);
    }
}
```

Now in Edit.cshtml, the following line of code is the first line (note that I am using an `ExtendedUser` object which inherits from `Microsoft.Graph.User`:

```
@model MyProjectName.Models.ExtendedUser
```

Like the commenters suggested, I didn't have to make any changes to the `@LabelFor` or `@TextBoxFor` code, but I just needed to return `myEditedUser` to the View.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get the same result using this EditorFor:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value="full name here" } })
```

TextBox and Editor are doing almost the same thing in this case ! I this there be not difference here !